# How to read csv without header in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I use

```
Adj = pd.read_csv('xxxxxx.csv', usecols=["Adj Close"])
```

to read my csv file and result is looks like:

```
       Adj Close
0      0.007427
1      0.002013
2      0.008874
```

my csv file look like:

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Adj Close
 x       x       x         x          x     832.349976
 x       x       x         x          x     832.349923
```

I trying to get the result like:

```
0      0.007427           or          0.007427
1      0.002013                       0.002013
2      0.008874                       0.008874
```

what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be confusing the output from your df with the actual data values, for instance you could just to `df.values` to convert the df to a numpy array, it's unclear what the issue here really is

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Adj = pd.read_csv('xxxxxx.csv', usecols=["Adj Close"])['Adj Close'].values
```

That will ingest the csv, select the `Adj Close` column, and then select the underlying numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
Adj = pd.read_csv('xxxxxx.csv', usecols=["Adj Close"], header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a csv file without header, do as follows:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None)
```

As [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) commented, the questions isn't clear. But this is the first google result when searching for reading a csv file without header. So, I've added a solution for that, in case somebody else lands here looking for a solution for that.