# Python: How to extract data from csv that has NO HEADERS

Tags: python, file, csv

This is the current code that i have:

```
with open('some_file.csv', mode='r') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0])
```

And I have a csv file that looks something like:

```
email@email.com,Name
email2@email.com, Name2
and so on...
```

But when I run this code, it automatically skips the 1st row because it thinks it is a header. I do not want to skip the 1st row and print everything out. How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: @rools: That is the opposite question (how to ignore the first line).

Comment: What about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387191/python-csv-without-header

Comment: In my tests (python2 and python3), it does not skip the first line, so I misread it. Sorry.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem. It prints the first line for me even without there being a header

Comment: I used `csv` package, which one did you use?

Comment: Same for me, both Python2 and 3 reads the first line, using csv.reader

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas and set header equal to None :

here is an example :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('some_file.csv', header=None)
```

Comment: good googling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056263/how-to-read-csv-without-header-in-pandas but he wants to use csv.reader

Comment: Ok, I tried with both python2 & 3, and csv.reader and it reads also the first line of my csv files

Comment: yeah I don't understand why he wants to use csv reader, he can just do for l in file:
a.split(sep)

Comment: @E.Serra Perhaps OP has quoted fields or escaped quotes.  `csv` handles that.  `split` doesn't.